# How to remove interaction from a map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, draw-interaction, modify-interaction, ol-interaction

as shown in the below posted code, when `digitize()` is called, the mouse cursor figure changes inidicating the i can start drawing a polyogn or a geometry on the map.

what i want to do, is when `deattachAll()` is called, i should remove the `#drawEvt` from the map so that the mouse cursor returns to the normal shape or figure/icon, but given the code below, that does not happen.

please let me know what i missing in the code and how to fix this issue

**code**

```
digitize() {
    this.#keyOnDrawStart = this.#drawEvt.on('drawstart', (evt) => this.#evtListenerOnDrawStart(
        evt, this.#vectorSource, this.#rasterLayer, this.#vectorLayer, this.#modifyEvt, this.#drawEvt, this.#snapEvt
    ));

    this.#keyOnDrawEnd = this.#drawEvt.on('drawend', (evt) => this.#evtListenerOnDrawEnd(
        evt, this.#mapBuilderInstance, this.#rasterLayer
    ));
    return;
}

deattachAll() {
    this.#mapInstance = this.#mapBuilderInstance.removeInteractionEvtFromMap(this.#mapInstance, this.#drawEvt);
}



removeInteractionEvtFromMap(map, evt) {
    if (map) {
        if (evt) {
            map.removeInteraction(evt);
            return map;
        } else {
            console.error('WTF. evt is not initialized. evt:', evt);
            throw new TypeError('WTF. evt is not initialized. evt:', evt);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('WTF. map is not initialized. map:', map);
        throw new TypeError('WTF. map is not initialized. map:', map);
    }
}
```